# Using firewall service in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

As In RHEL or Centos, we can make load port or service permanently by:

```
firewall-cmd --reload.
```

But currently I am working on ubuntu 16.04 but I dont have that much knowledge about this.

So please tell me to add port or service in firewall and make it permanent.

I am using command:

```
sudo ufw allow https or 443/tcp
```

Is it the same in RHEL or CENTOS?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 does not use `firewalld` by default such as RHEL/Centos which is why `firewall-cmd --reload` will not work . So you have 3 options:

1) Switch to **firewalld** by:

`sudo systemctl stop iptables
sudo systemctl mask iptables
sudo apt-get remove ufw
apt install firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld`

2) Use **iptables** by:

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --d-port 443 -j ACCEPT`

3) Use **UFW** by:

`sudo ufw allow 443`

Comment: Yes. It works..